# PhpStorm Xdebug project cross debugging

Tags: php, debugging, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I have 2 projects: [Backend-project, Frontend-project]
Both are using Laravel framework and both are hosted on same vagrant box under same nginx, I am using PhpStorm IDE, I successfully managed to configure xdebug for projects (separately)

Xdebug config as following for both projects:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.66.7
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

Frontend-project talk to Backend-project through and API, I have full access to both projects.

My question is how can I configure xdebug so when I make a request from frontend-project to Backend-project.

I mean I want to put break point on Backend-project and do a request from frontend-project.

Comment: 1) `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` is a must have here (other possible approaches are messy). 2) Ensure that "phone handle" icon is activated in both projects 3) You may need to increase the max number of simultaneous debug connections in PhpStorm settings (hint: use Search box) to be more than default `1`, in both projects, I guess. 4) May need to configure separate `PHP | Servers` entry -- but with default settings IDE should help with this. It should work (if all setup correctly)  -- you are not the first one who tries to do such setup.

Comment: If you need to simulate request from front-end -- you can use `Tools | Test RESTful Web Service` window (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Built-in+REST+Client+in+PhpStorm) or custom Run/Debug Configuration (e.g. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/debugging-a-php-http-request.html)